# Slick slider c абсолютно позиционированным элементом

Tags: html, css, css3

Используется [плагин](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

В примере ниже внутри слайда размещается точка с абсолютным позиционированием, и если точка выходит за границы то ее не видно

[Пример](https://jsfiddle.net/fmo50w7n/1098/)

HTML

```
<section class="slider">
    <div>slide1
        <div class="point"></div>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
$c1: #3a8999;
$c2: #e84a69;

.slider {
    width: auto;
    margin: 30px 50px 50px;
}

.slick-slide {
    background: $c1;
    color: white;
    padding: 40px 0;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: "Arial", "Helvetica";
    text-align: center;
}

.slick-prev:before, 
.slick-next:before {
    color: black;    
}

.slick-dots {
    bottom: -30px;
}

.slick-slide:nth-child(odd) {
     background: $c2;
}

.point {
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

JS

```
$(".slider").slick({
    autoplay: true,
    dots: true,
});
```

Если убрать у блока slick-list свойство overflow: hidden, то точка появляется, но начнает ехать верстка других блоков

Вопрос Как разместить точку, чтобы ее было видно при этом не изменяя свойств плагина?

Важно: точка размещается имеено внутри слайдера и у нее абсолютное позиционирование относительно слайда

Answer (score 1):

например, задать отступ внутри слайда (вместо того чтобы выносить за его пределы):

```js
/**

    This fiddle is using the latest version 
    of Slick (from master) and jQuery.

    If your issue occurs in older version or a 
    specific tag; please use the "External Resources" 
    section in the sidebar to correct it.

**/


$(".slider").slick({
    autoplay: true,
    dots: true,
    responsive: [{ 
        breakpoint: 500,
        settings: {
            dots: false,
            arrows: false,
            infinite: false,
            slidesToShow: 2,
            slidesToScroll: 2
        } 
    }]
});
```

```css
$c1: #3a8999;
$c2: #e84a69;

.slider {
    width: auto;
    margin: 30px 50px 50px;
}

.slick-slide {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.slick-slide__inner {
    background: #3a8999;
    color: white;
    padding: 40px 0;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: "Arial", "Helvetica";
    text-align: center;
}

.slick-prev:before, 
.slick-next:before {
    color: black;    
}

.slick-dots {
    bottom: -30px;
}

.slick-slide:nth-child(odd) .slick-slide__inner{
     background: #e84a69;
}

.point {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>

<!--              ^
    Use the FORK, Luke.
    create your own new fiddle test case.
-->

<section class="slider">
    <div>
        <div class="slick-slide__inner">
          Slide 1
          <div class="point"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="slick-slide__inner">
          Slide 2
          <div class="point"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: не вариант, потому что условна точка может быть больше самого слайдера по высоте, например popover

Comment: и этот поповер должен быть виден за пределами слайдера

Comment: @ruslik, сразу бы и писали в вопросе что поповер, а не точка. Поповер обычно fixed делают абсолют тут не поможет.

Comment: и высота поповера может меняться в зависиомти от контента в нем